# Out of date suppliments to potting mix

Tags: plant-health, potting-soil

I found these expired calcium suppliments while cleaning. Some of them are solid tablets and some are soft gelatin capsules.

Now the crazy question is:

1. Can we put these suppliments in the potting mix in general?
2. If so, will it be a good idea to use these **expired pills**?

Comment: Calcium is neutral-to-alkaline and good for most plants. Not acid lovers like azalea, camelia, roses, and blueberries. But expired is a vague term, and I'd use them both. Probably the texture is blah.

Comment: Okay..they will be straight into the soil :D